# sh equivalent of __FILE__

Tags: php, file, shell

Is there a sh equivalent of `__FILE__`, to give me the pathname of the currently executing file?  POSIX solutions preferred, bash acceptable, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a Bash script tell what directory it's stored in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `$0`.

Comment: This is not equivalent to `__FILE__` if you are doing it in a file that is sourced from another file.

Answer (score 2):

This will grab both the file and the directory

```
# !/bin/sh

# store where we are
__PWD__=$(pwd)
# go to the current file (i.e. this file)
cd $(dirname $0)
# gives the file name, __FILE__
echo $0
__FILE__=$0
# gives the directory name, __DIR__
echo $(dirname $0)
__DIR__=$(dirname $0)
# this has been a test of the Linux filesystem; we now return you to your previous program.. :)
cd $__PWD__
```

Answer (score 1):

For a bash script solution

[Getting the source directory of a Bash script from within](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-in)

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# "$0" will expand to the name of the script, as called from the command line
readlink -f $0
```

Comment: That will be incorrect if the script is called via the $PATH variable.

Comment: Note that `readlink` isn't entirely portable. OSX (and presumably BSD in general?) have a completely different version - where `-f` isn't supported. Rather, where `-f` means something different (and not helpful here).

Comment: `echo $(readlink -f $0)` works fine on OSX 10.6, just tested it.

Comment: Why are you using `echo`. Doesn't `readlink -f $0` by itself work?

Comment: @The MYYN You must have gnu's `coreutils` installed without the `g` prefixes. Here's what happens when I run that command: `readlink: illegal option -- f` (Yes, I'm on 10.6. I actually have gnu's `readlink` as well, but only under the alias `greadlink`. http://pastie.org/1057557 for an example.)